# Testcafe - Is there any possibility to use more than one User Role to execute Same test cases in Test cafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are using Test cafe for the automation. The case here is like, there are three user roles like Admin, Manager and Employee. We have test cases where we need to check the same functionality which applies to combination of users (i.e more than one user role) like Admin and Manager user roles OR Manager and Employee OR all three user roles.
Test cafe allows to use the useRole method. However, it satisfies only when we want to execute test case for one user role. When it comes to a situation, where two or more user roles need to be used to execute same set of test cases, we couldn't find a proper solution.
Can anyone please help us to resolve this or is there any other way to find solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute each test case with each role. Please take a look at the following example:

```js
import { t } from "testcafe";
const roles = { admin, manager, employee };

fixture('Fixture 1').page('https://www.example.com');

for (const roleName in roles) {
    test(`Test 1, role: ${roleName}`, async () => {
        await t.useRole(roles[roleName]);
    });
}
```

There are three user roles in the example. I used the `for… in …` loop to go through them and execute a test case for each of them independently.